# grep word and regex from a file

Tags: linux, regex, grep

I have a file that has some server names. Some servers are with regex and some are without. I am trying to grep if the server is present in that file or not and I only have server names with me.

My file has

```
srv-tst-a1
srv-dev-a1
srv-tst-db[1-2]
srv-dev-a[2-5]
srv1-(dev|qa)-a[1-5]
srv1-tst-(db|app)
```

how to grep if srv-dev-a4 is present in the file.

Best Regards,
KJ.reg

Comment: This is a [PCRE regex](https://regex101.com/r/0xM3zr/1), does it work for you: `srv-dev-a(4|\[[1-4]-[4-5]\])`?

Comment: I am looking for simple Grep or awk to search.

Comment: `grep -P /srv-dev-a(4|\[[1-4]-[4-5]\])/`

Comment: can you please explain what is \[[1-4]-[4-5]\] in the command.

Comment: `\[` matches an opening square bracket, `[1-4]` a digit from 1 to 4, `-` a dash, `[4-5]` a digit from 4 to 5, `\]` a closing square bracket. See the link provided above. If it works for you, I'll make this comment an answer.